# Issue when use two type-cast operators in template class

Tags: c++

I define a template class in which, I define two type-cast operator

```
template <class base_t>
struct subclass {

  base_t base;

  //any function which defined for 'base_t' can be used with 'subclass<base_t>'
  operator base_t&() {
    return base;
  }

  //I want 'subclass<base_t>' can be converted to any class which 'base_t' can
  //I want this operator is called only if 'target_t' is not 'base_t'
  template <class target_t>
  operator target_t&() {
    return (target_t)base;
  }

};
```

The class looks fine, but there're a problem when I try to convert `subclass<int>` to `int`. For instance:

```
typedef subclass<int> foo_t;
foo_t foo = {1234};
cout << foo << endl; //Error here: ambiguous; This line is compiled only if I delete 'template<class target_t> operator target_t&()'
```

Please tell me how

**EDIT**

Everything work fine if I don't define the template. However, if I define a `subclass< subclass<int> >`, I can convert it to `subclass<int>` but I can't convert it to `int`

```
typedef subclass<int> level1;
typedef subclass<level1> level2;
level1 a = {1234};
level2 b = {a};
cout << a << endl;
cout << b << endl; //Error! Because the compiler doesn't provide a type-cast from level2 to int
```

Comment: What do you want the template conversion to even do? You're currently allowing `foo` to be converted to `char&` and `double&` and `bool&` and ... None of those conversions are reasonable. All of them are viable candidates for `operator<<`, hence the ambiguity.

Comment: @Barry I know why it is ambiguous, what I want to do is convert it to `int` because its `base_t` is `int`, not the other

Comment: That's what your non-template `operator` does already. Why do you need the template one?

Comment: @Barry if I don't define the template, everything works fine. However, when I define, `subclass < subclass<int> >` and it can converted to `subclass<int>` but can't be converted to `int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do makes little sense.

We have `subclass<int>`. It is convertible to `int&`, but also to a lot of other reference types. `char&`. `bool&`. `double&`. The ambiguity arises from the fact that all the various overloads for `operator<<` that take any non-template argument are viable overload candidates with equivalent conversion sequences. And for good measure, you probably don't want to do any of those conversions anyway.

What you want is *just* the `base&` `operator`:

```
template <class base_t>
struct subclass {
    base_t base;

    operator base_t&();
};
```

That's really all you need. This gives you the reference implicitly to the type you're storing, and you can already take base-class references to it too:

```
subclass<Derived> obj;
Base& base = obj; // totally OK with just that one operator
```

I don't see what problem the template `operator T&` solves.

> However, when I define, `subclass < subclass<int> >` and it can converted to `subclass<int>` but can't be converted to `int`

First of all, `subclass<subclass<int>>` can be converted to `subclass<int>&`, not `subclass<int>`. That said, if we want that to work, we can add a conversion operator **specifically** for that case. First, add a type trait to find what the most nested type is:

```
template <class base_t>
struct subclass;

template <typename T>
struct nested { using type = T; };

template <typename T>
struct nested<subclass<T>> : nested<T> { };
```

And then define a template `operator` conversion for the nested case:

```
template <typename T, 
          typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, typename nested<base_t>::type>::value>>
operator T&() {
    return base;
}
```

We make it a template so that there isn't an ambiguous overload in the case where we're just one `subclass` deep. And with that, both of these work:

```
subclass<subclass<subclass<int>>> s{{{4}}};
int& i = s;

subclass<int> s2{5};
int& i2 = s2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bit of SFINAE techniques to make this work

```
template <class target_t, class = std::enable_if< !std::is_same<target_t, base_t>::value && std::is_convertible<base_t, target_t>::value> >
operator target_t&() {
    return (target_t)base;
}
```

Not the best syntax in the world, but that's how C++ currently works until Concepts Lite are standardized

Comment: I'm not sure if I got the order of the "is_convertible" right. I know the left one is "from" and the second one "to", but I'm not sure which way OP wanted it to go. I'll edit if needed

Comment: You want the other way around -- from base to target.  That is what the cast does.  Of course the code still won't work...